# "Указать" с предлогом и без предлога

Tags: предлоги

"Указывать на предмет" и "указывать предмет" - одинаково допустимые варианты?

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от значения. Розенталь в словаре "Управление в русском языке" объясняет:

> УКАЗАТЬ — 1. [**показать; привести; перечислить; установить; назвать для
>   сведения] что**. Указать срок уплаты долга; Указать пособия по курсу;
>   Ваше одно слово напомнило мне мой долг, указало мне мою дорогу (Т.);
>   ...Указав все их недостатки и положительные стороны (Н. О.).
>
> 2.> **[обратить внимание; движением, жестом показать на кого-что-л.] на
>   кого-что.** Указать на девушек, стоящих у стены зала; ...Указав глазами
>   на высокие болотные сапоги, в которых пришёл Соломин (Т.).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Answer (score 0):

Согласно слрварю Управление в русском языке ( Д.Э. Розенталь) в зависимости  от смысла допустимы оба варианта.

УКАЗАТЬ — 1. [показать; привести; перечислить; установить; назвать для сведения] что. Указать срок уплаты долга; Указать пособия по курсу; Ваше одно слово напомнило мне мой долг, указало мне мою дорогу (Т.); ...Указав все их недостатки и положительные стороны (Н. О.). 2. [обратить внимание; движением, жестом показать на кого-что-л.] на кого-что. Указать на девушек, стоящих у стены зала; ...Указав глазами на высокие болотные сапоги, в которых пришёл Соломин (Т.).

В вашем примере, как видим, правильно с предлогом: указать на предмет.